# Any suggestion to enchance performance for a macro defined function with autoload?

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp, autoload

```
(defmacro create-function (function-name)
  `(defun ,function-name ()
     "Say hello to world."
     (interactive)
     ;; A heavy function body here
     (message ,(symbol-name function-name))))
```

It demonstrates a macro defining a function.

I am writing a package to let user create a function with desired name and corresponding usage. The function created will be used globally (in other words, it is not mode specific). However, the user may or may not really need the function. But once they need, the function needs to be available.

```
(create-function foobar1)
(create-function foobar2)
;; ....................
(create-function foobar20)
```

This `(create-function x)` is likely to be put in user's config file and expanded at startup time so that the function is prepared. So, I think autoloading the macro is meaningless.

However, the function created may not be always needed and there is no pattern when the user need. In addition, the function is not use very often, say, only use three of them per session. So, my idea is to autoload the function.

Unlike normal function, this functions are defined in a macro body. Autoload may not be able to find the function definition at runtime.

I also tried to make a prototype macro like this:

```
(defmacro create-function-prototype (function-name)
  `(defun ,function-name ()
     (interactive)
     (create-function ,function-name)
     (call-interactively (quote ,function-name)))
```

My another idea is to create a blank function with no function body first. It seems to be working. Does the flow work as expected?

---

To sum up, there are three questions

1. Is autoloading this macro meaningful?
2. Can I autolaod function defined in a marco?
3. Is the prototype method working?

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to optimize.  So, which part do you find to be too slow?  What have you measured?

Comment: In fact, I did not measure the performance. I am just brain storming whether doing so can help improve performance. I did try to implement all the things I mentioned. They seems to be working fine (at least no error). But I am not sure if they are doing their job as expected or they are redundant.

Comment: From my understanding, if you put all the functions in one file, autoloading one function will load the others too.

Comment: Looks like you don't have a performance problem, so there's no possible "solution" by virtue of there not being any "problem".